# createAsyncThunk throws error but case rejected does not get triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using the following createAsyncThunk to delete an application in the db.

For some reason the fetch is not working. `handleFetchErrors` throws an Error if the response is not OK

```
export const handleFetchErrors = (response: Response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText)
        }
}

export const deleteApplication = createAsyncThunk("applications/deleteApplication", async (data: any) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/application/${data.id}`, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        //fixme: call still gets fulfilled although I am throwing an error
        handleFetchErrors(response);
        return (data.id);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
})
```

In my `createSlice` I am using these extraReducers for the upper case

```
 .addCase(deleteApplication.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                state.status = DataFetchingStatus.succeeded
                state.applications = state.applications.filter(application => application.id !== action.payload)
            })
            .addCase(deleteApplication.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.status = DataFetchingStatus.failed
                state.error = action.payload
            })
```

The `deleteApplication.fulfilled` is getting triggered instead of the `deleteApplication.rejected`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handleFetchErrors` function throws an error, but this error is caught by `deleteApplication` and merely printed as a console message. Hence, `deleteApplication.rejected` is never dispatched. I suggest either (a) not catching the error; or (b) re-throwing the error in the catch block.